# Angular 7 SyntaxError: expected expression, got '< in production when ever basehref change from root

Tags: angular, angular7

Whenever I change basehref to "/v2/" (or any other value other than "/") via ng `build --prod --base-href /v2/` I get the following error:

Angular 7 SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Comment: can you add more details like the stacktrace?
also `--base-href` should be your actual base-href.
in your case `/v2/`

Comment: Where can I find the logs/ stacktrace? I updated tp add the exact line.

Comment: Did you actually resolve this?

Comment: please select best answer

Answer (score 1):

this is an overkill:

```
ng build --aot --prod
```

because prod always performs aot so that parameter is not needed, please use:

```
ng build --prod --base-href
```

Source: https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Also < base href="/v2"> instead of < base href="/v2/">

Then to make sure the assets are not lost I added a folder src/app/v2/assets/images and updated the css to reference the new path and the angular.json

```
"assets": ["src/favicon.ico","src/v2/assets"]
```

Comment: it works in ng serve - development environment. `ng build --prod --base-href` this doesn't change the results.

Comment: My guess is that it will fail in NG SERVE --AOT

Comment: also <base href="/v2"> instead of <base href="/v2/">

Comment: The error is gone, but all the assets including css, main*.js, runtime*.js doesnt have the  /v2/main*.js in its location

Comment: Yes, I had the same problem, I added a folder src/app/v2/assets/images and updated the css to reference the new path and the angular.json "assets": ["src/favicon.ico","src/v2/assets"]

Answer (score 0):

I have too noticed this behaviour migrating from v6 -> v7.
If you are using routing try using your wildcard route (**) as this

```
{
    path: '', component: DashboardComponent, children: [
      { path: 'comp1', component: FirstComponent },
      { path: 'comp2', component: SecondComponent },
      { path: 'comp3', component: ThirdComponent },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: '/comp1', pathMatch: 'full'}
    ]
}
```

In v6 this was working as well, but not in v7

```
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'comp1', pathMatch: 'full'}
```

Long story short, if you add this at the end of your routing paths, it should work

```
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full'}
```