# How to build an Angular 5 project when it will be hosted in a sub-folder?

Tags: angular

I am trying to build an Angular 5 project that will be hosted in a sub-folder.  We're in the process of upgrading to 7, but we're not there yet.

The web server is hosting a main folder on port 8080.  I'm trying to build by Angular 5 project so it can be hosted in a sub-folder titled AC-672.  So the final url to get to it would be ipAddress:8080/AC-672

In app.module.ts

```
imports: [
  AppRoutingModule,
  BrowserAnimationsModule,
  BrowserModule,
  CommonModule,
  HttpClientModule,
  NgbModule.forRoot(),
  RuntimeConfigLoaderModule.forRoot({
    fileUrl: './assets/config/config.json'
  })
]
```

In the terminal I've tried a variety of build commands.  But I keep getting errors or it's hosted at a weird address.
Here are a couple of the commands I've tried.

```
ng-build --aot --build-optimizer --base-href AC-672 --deploy-url AC-672
ng-build --aot --build-optimizer --base-href AC-672
ng-build --aot --build-optimizer --deploy-url AC-672
ng-build --aot --build-optimizer
ng-build --aot --build-optimizer --base-href /AC-672/ --deploy-url /AC-672/
ng-build --aot --build-optimizer --base-href /AC-672/ --deploy-url AC-672
ng-build --aot --build-optimizer --base-href AC-672 --deploy-url /AC-672/
ng-build --aot --build-optimizer --base-href /AC-672/
ng-build --aot --build-optimizer --deploy-url /AC-672/
```

I am obviously missing something.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will deploy the folder inside the original deployment folder and then correct the base href and assets like this:

index.html

```
< base href="/AC-672">
```

angular.json

```
"assets": ["src/favicon.ico","src/AC-672/assets"]
```

Also read this question and answer: [Angular 7 SyntaxError: expected expression, got '< in production when ever basehref change from root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54986643/angular-7-syntaxerror-expected-expression-got-in-production-when-ever-baseh/54986780?noredirect=1#comment96733261_54986780)

Source: https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Answer (score 0):

In your index.html this should be your base href:

```
<base href="/">
```

Set the base href in your build command like this:

```
ng build --base-href=/AC-672/
```